# 'For Each' loop not looping through rows with repeating ID's

Tags: vba, excel

This is a part of a VBA macro that alters order information exported from an online shop to be later imported into a shipping manager.

The code below is doing what it is meant to do which is replace the CRL1/2 with STL1/2 if the criteria is met.

The issue arising is when a single order from the shop is split into separate rows with the same order number in column A for each row. The macro only processes the first of the rows with the same order number.

```
  Dim Cel7_Lastrow As Integer
  Cel7_Lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim Rng As Range
  Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & Cel7_Lastrow)

  For Each Cel7 In Rng
      Dim Lookup_Range2 As Range

      Country_Name = Cel7.Value2
      C_Code = Cel7.Value2
      Weight_V = Cel7.Value2

      Set Lookup_Range2 = Sheet2.Range("A2:R" & Cel7_Lastrow)
      Country = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Country_Name,Lookup_Range2, 8, False)
      Code = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(C_Code,Lookup_Range2, 13, False)
      Weight = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Weight_V,Lookup_Range2, 18, False)

      If Country = "GB" And Code = "CRL1" And Weight <= 0.1 Then
             Cel7.Offset(0, 12).Value = "STL1"
      End If

      If Country = "GB" And Code = "CRL2" And Weight <= 0.1 Then
             Cel7.Offset(0, 12).Value = "STL2"
      End If        
 Next Cel7
```

Comment: Since the VLOOKUP takes the first value where there's a match, once it was changed to `STL1` if won't implement more changes after the first one's. `Country = Cel7.Offset(0,7) | Code = Cel7.Offset(0,12) | Weight = Cel7.Offset(0,17)` won't use lookup.

Comment: Would the INDEX/MATCH function be better for this

Comment: Nope, MATCH takes first match too.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your help

Comment: Did what you suggested, removed the Vlookup section and replaced It with Country = Cel7.Offset(0,7).Value & Code = Cel7.Offset(0,12).Value & Weight = Cel7.Offset(0,17).Value and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but I think a loop will perform much better than lookups

```
Dim Cel7_Lastrow As Integer
Cel7_Lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To Cel7_Lastrow
    If Sheet2.Cells(r, 8) = "GB" And Sheet2.Cells(r, 18) <= 0.1 Then
      If Sheet2.Cells(r, 13) = "CRL1" Then Sheet2.Cells(r, 13) = "STL1"
      If Sheet2.Cells(r, 13) = "CRL2" Then Sheet2.Cells(r, 13) = "STL2"
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Thanks Figured it out from comment above, but this clarifies it nicely